# Python & Pyglet Minecraft Example Code Error

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.3, pyglet

So I built Pyglet on my Mac and I tried using it with a Minecraft (Python) demo code, but I got this error, and I realize that it stems from Pyglet itself. Here is the complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/PyCraft/main.py", line 892, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/PyCraft/main.py", line 890, in main
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 123, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 127, in run
    self._legacy_setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 218, in _legacy_setup
    window.dispatch_pending_events()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/window/cocoa/__init__.py", line 324, in dispatch_pending_events
    EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *event)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 369, in dispatch_event
    event_type, args, getattr(self, event_type))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 365, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/PyCraft/main.py", line 767, in on_resize
    ('v2i', (x - n, y, x + n, y, x, y - n, x, y + n))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/__init__.py", line 289, in vertex_list
    return _get_default_batch().add(count, 0, None, *data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/__init__.py", line 359, in add
    vlist._set_attribute_data(i, array)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/vertexdomain.py", line 440, in _set_attribute_data
    region.array[:] = data
TypeError: int expected instead of float
```

Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/PyCraft/main.py", line 767, in on_resize
    ('v2i', (x - n, y, x + n, y, x, y - n, x, y + n))
```

and:

```
def on_resize(self, width, height):
        """ Called when the window is resized to a new `width` and `height`.

        """
        # label
        self.label.y = height - 10
        # reticle
        if self.reticle:
            self.reticle.delete()
        x, y = self.width / 2, self.height / 2
```

v2i, i stands for integer, but you are passing floats. Change last line to

```
        x, y = self.width // 2, self.height // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic typerror is that you are trying to set a number (IE 1) as a float (IE 1.1). 
Having your code on paste bin would be very useful.

Thanks, Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like another problem lies in the fact that you are using Python 3.3. Pyglet supports 2.x.

Comment: I did 2to3 it but I imagine that won't cover anything. Thanks.